# Not rotating the bitmap

Tags: java, android

I want to rotate bitmap in the specific angle which is `angle = meulerZ`

```
if (noseBasePos != null) {
    float width = op.getWidth()/2;
    float height = op.getHeight()/1.35f;
    int centrex = (int) (noseBasePos.x - width);
    int centrey = (int) (noseBasePos.y - height);

    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.setRotate(meulerZ);
    mat.postRotate(meulerZ);
    mat.setTranslate(centrex,centrey);
    op = Bitmap.createBitmap(op, 0,0,op.getWidth(), op.getHeight(), mat, true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(op,mat,null);
}
```

Comment: And... what is the problem? And... what is the question? And the angle is 90 degrees?

Comment: actually i am tryiing to develop a face filter app and i am drawing bitmap on face properly...and now i want to rotate the bitmap in that angle in which head is tilt. so angle is not specific....meuler z is the angle of head tilt.

Comment: And... what is the problem? And... what is the question? And the angle is 90 degrees?